# Need a comprehensive tutorial on OpenERP 7.0

Tags: odoo

I am working on OpenERP. But I am not getting its stuff. Please help me. I have Google a lot but nothing meaningful. I Need to understand the flow of information in OpenERP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Document](https://doc.openerp.com/) will help you to learn OpenERP. Here you can get Technical Documentation, Tutorial, Ebooks, for version 5.0 onward. just discover it!

Comment: No. There is not enough details which give some understanding of the flow.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with user 2310840! There's a lot of information for OpenERP 'out there' but it's often too overwhelming, complex or irrelevant for end users. As a result, it's just unclear how all the pieces of the puzzle work together...

For instance, the link of Atul Arvind to the 'Document' is idd a good starting point. However, this is not just a 'document' but rather a link to the official online 'knowledge base'. The table of content for the OpenERP Tutorial alone consists of more than 16 pages! This approach is similar as being forced to read your car manual from top to bottom, before even being able to start your engine...

That's the main reason we recently launched our website 'OERPtuts'. We'll provide easy to follow, step-by-step tutorials for OpenERP end users. You can read our first 'official launch' post at http://oerptuts.com/articles/news/launch-time/. If you want to receive automatic updates on future posts, please subscribe to the newsletter on our website.